# Get children from gtk.ScrolledWindow

Tags: gtk, pygtk

i have Window and gtk.ScrolledWindow on it, and gtk.TextView in this scrooledWindow. How can i get textview?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
window.get_child().get_child()
```

Comment: Or `scroll.get_child()`.

Comment: 2023: child = scrolled_window_get_child(); if (child is viewport) child = child_as_viewport_get_child();